The trajectory of a charged particle in an electrostatic field
If I release a particle which is initially at rest in an electrostatic field (there is no other force that acts on it), would its trajectory be independent of its mass?
I mean the shape of the trajectory, I am aware that particles with different mass should arrive a given point at different times.

what do you mean by shape?
We've all solved the horizontal air-free ballistic problem, where you get a parabola based on $v$ and $g$, so the shape of the parabola is determined by $g \rightarrow qE/m$.
Or a (bound) orbit type problem with $E\sim1/r^2 $. If
$$ \frac{mv^2} r = qE $$
it's a circle, and if not: it's an ellipse. Are circles (which are ellipses) consider the same shape as an ellipse (that is not a circle)?
If yes, then is the unbound case, a hyperbola, also the same shape (conic sections are conic sections)?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The question of mass independence depends on which other quantities are kept constant (Similar to thermodynamics). Consider the following cases

The mass $m$ of the particle is varied, while the absolute charge $Q$ is fixed
The mass $m$ of the particle is varied while the relative charge $R:= \frac{Q}{m}$ is fixed.

In the first case, the particle's trajectory does depend on the mass parameter $m$ since the force $\vec F = Q \cdot \vec E$ is the same, but the mass is different so the equations of motions are
$$\ddot {\vec x} = \frac{1}{m} Q \vec E$$.
In the second case, the particles's trajectory does not change with the mass parameter since the equations of motions are always.
$$\ddot{\vec x} = R \vec E$$
In other words the change in Coulomb force cancels the change in mass such that the acceleration is always the same.

In general one should pay attention when discussing counterfactual conditionals. E.g., consider the folling sentence "If Alice wouldn't be here with us, there would be an implosion of the air surrounding the place Alice is right now."

So you are saying in English langauge, when I ask whether something is dependent on mass, I should mention I am talking about "mass" not "speific charge"?

Generally speaking not. Consider a a one-dimensional case with an electric potential $U(x)$, so that:
$$
m\ddot{x}=-q\frac{dU(x)}{dx}.
$$
Such a trajectory corresponds to a motion with a constant energy:
$$
E=\frac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}+qU(x)
$$
Now, we can easily find a potential where the trajectories would be different, depending on the value of energy - e.g., if the potential has barriers, and the energy can be below or above the barrier, like this one (image source):

The caveat is that the initial energy depends on the initial conditions ($\dot{x}(t_0), x(t_0)$) - one could adjust the initial conditions to have the same trajectory for a different mass. However, in the case specified in the Q., where we start with zero initial velocity at a specified point, we can always adjust the units of time to have a unit mass:
$$
\sqrt{m}\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=\frac{dx(\tau)}{d\tau},
$$
so that the energy is
$$
E=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dx(\tau)}{d\tau}\right)^2+qU(x)
$$
We thus obtain for every mass the same shape trajectory, which differs only by squeezing the trajectory along the momentum axis.
The same trick can be done in any number of dimensions.

initial condition is stated in the question that particle is initially at rest. So in your 1-d example, both kinetic energy and potential energy gained by the particle is independent of the mass. (kinetic energy is equal to the integral of electric force over distance). Therefore, they have the same trajectory in 1-dimensional case

@disbeyce indeed, you can choose the time scale, such that the mass is unity.

@disbeyce I corrected my answer to include your initial conditions.
